# Webpage Loading on Ideal Forms Form & Possible Bug

Tags: jquery, forms, webforms

I have a jQuery form which was created by idealforms.

These forms are validated by the jQuery which alerts the user to errors and more info. but whenever a page loads with ideal forms intergrated, the page loads on the form with a form error message displays for the first field i.e "Required Field".

I have never encountered an issue like this and would like the form to not display an error until the user clicks the field and load the webpage at the top.

I have numerous pages with this error, an example is here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/104598901/Website/business.html

I look forward to getting this issue resolved and welcome any comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of Ideal Forms. By default this shouldn't happen unless you use the `focusFirst` method. Delete line 233 in your HTML.

```
$myform.focusFirst(); // delete this line
```

That will do.

Comment: thanks elclanrs. It worked perfectly, this has driven me mad for hours so many many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is intrinsic to the plugin you are using. Unfortunately the code is minimized so I can't give you any pointers within the code itself.

It's possible that you can override it with this:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
  if($(this).text().length < 1){
     event.stopPropagation();
   }
   else{

     }
 })
```

This *should* stop it from showing up if there's nothing in the field, but I can't exactly say given that I don't know the plugin and don't have access to its internals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried this but it made no difference. I have tried to find the developer contact details to no avail. Thank you for the support all the same!